# Field Can Be Made Readonly

Tags: c#, meta-programming, roslyn

Here is my Field Can Be Made Readonly analyzer and quick fix.  I would appreciate tips on how to improve my code, and on missed test cases.

First, the rules it works with:

1. It will only fire on `private` fields to make things simpler (fields in other scopes should be properties, anyway).
2. If the field is only assigned inline or in the ctor, it should be `readonly`
3. Fields cannot be `readonly` if they are:
   A. Assigned in any scope other than a ctor or inline.
   B. Passed as a `ref` or `out` argument.
   C. Incremented or decremented with the prefix or postfix `++` or `--` operators.

Here is the analyzer code:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class FieldCanBeReadonlyAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private const DiagnosticSeverity Severity = DiagnosticSeverity.Warning;

    private static readonly string Category = VSDiagnosticsResources.GeneralCategory;
    private static readonly string Message = VSDiagnosticsResources.FieldCanBeReadonlyAnalyzerMessage;
    private static readonly string Title = VSDiagnosticsResources.FieldCanBeReadonlyAnalyzerTitle;

    internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule => new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId.FieldCanBeReadonly, Title, Message, Category, Severity, true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context) => context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration, SyntaxKind.StructDeclaration);

    private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var classSymbol = (ITypeSymbol)context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node);
        if (classSymbol.TypeKind != TypeKind.Class &&
            classSymbol.TypeKind != TypeKind.Struct)
        {
            return;
        }

        var nonReadonlyFieldMembers = new List<IFieldSymbol>();
        foreach (var item in classSymbol.GetMembers())
        {
            var symbol = item as IFieldSymbol;
            if (symbol != null && symbol.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Private && !symbol.IsReadOnly)
            {
                nonReadonlyFieldMembers.Add(symbol);
            }
        }

        var membersCanBeReadonly = nonReadonlyFieldMembers;
        foreach (var syntaxReference in classSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
        {
            var classNode = syntaxReference.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().FindNode(syntaxReference.Span);
            membersCanBeReadonly = WalkTree(context.SemanticModel, classNode, membersCanBeReadonly);
        }

        foreach (var symbol in membersCanBeReadonly)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name));
        }
    }

    private static List<IFieldSymbol> WalkTree(SemanticModel model, SyntaxNode node, List<IFieldSymbol> unassignedSymbols)
    {
        // todo check whether node is reference to a field
        // check whether reference is assignment or ref/out param
        foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes())
        {
            if (child is ConstructorDeclarationSyntax)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(child).Symbol as IFieldSymbol;
            if (symbol != null && unassignedSymbols.Contains(symbol))
            {
                var assignmentNode = child.Parent as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
                if (assignmentNode?.Left == child)
                {
                    unassignedSymbols.Remove(symbol);
                }

                var argumentNode = child.Parent as ArgumentSyntax;
                if (argumentNode?.RefOrOutKeyword != null)
                {
                    unassignedSymbols.Remove(symbol);
                }

                var postFixExpressionNode = child.Parent as PostfixUnaryExpressionSyntax;
                if (postFixExpressionNode != null)
                {
                    unassignedSymbols.Remove(symbol);
                }

                var preFixExpressionNode = child.Parent as PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax;
                if (preFixExpressionNode != null)
                {
                    unassignedSymbols.Remove(symbol);
                }
            }

            unassignedSymbols = WalkTree(model, child, unassignedSymbols);
        }

        return unassignedSymbols;
    }
}
```

The code fix adds the `readonly` keyword to the node:

```
[ExportCodeFixProvider(DiagnosticId.FieldCanBeReadonly + "CF", LanguageNames.CSharp), Shared]
public class FieldCanBeReadonlyCodeFix : CodeFixProvider
{
    public override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds => ImmutableArray.Create(FieldCanBeReadonlyAnalyzer.Rule.Id);

    public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider() => WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;

    public override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
        var diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;

        var fieldDeclaration = (FieldDeclarationSyntax)root.FindNode(diagnosticSpan).Parent.Parent;

        context.RegisterCodeFix(
            CodeAction.Create(VSDiagnosticsResources.FieldCanBeReadonlyCodeFixTitle,
                x => MakeReadonlyAsync(context.Document, root, fieldDeclaration), FieldCanBeReadonlyAnalyzer.Rule.Id), diagnostic);
    }

    private Task<Document> MakeReadonlyAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode root, FieldDeclarationSyntax declaration)
    {
        var newDeclaration = declaration.AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ReadOnlyKeyword));

        var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(declaration, newDeclaration);
        var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
        return Task.FromResult(newDocument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var nonReadonlyFieldMembers = new List<IFieldSymbol>();
> ...
> unassignedSymbols.Contains(symbol)
> ...
> unassignedSymbols.Remove(symbol);
> ```

If this needs to be fast, then using a `HashSet<IFieldSymbol>` might be a good idea.

The `Contains` and `Remove` methods you're currently using perform a linear search, which means those operations are *O(n)*. With a `HashSet`, both would be *O(1)* (if you don't need to maintain the order, of course).

---

I think the `WalkTree` method should be split into two—that is, extract the filtering logic into a new method and let `WalkTree` do only tree scanning.

It now takes a delegate that can do something with a `child`. The result is generic so it should even be possible to reuse it. The `HashSet<T>` is passed around by reference so there's no need to return it.

```
private static void WalkTree<TResult>(
    SemanticModel model,
    SyntaxNode node,
    HashSet<TResult> results,
    Action<SemanticModel, SyntaxNode, HashSet<TResult>> processNode)
{
    // TODO: check whether node is reference to a field
    // TODO: check whether reference is assignment or ref/out param
    foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes())
    {
        if (child is ConstructorDeclarationSyntax)
        {
            continue;
        }

        processNode(model, child, results);

        WalkTree(model, child, results, processNode);
    }   
}
```

The filtering logic now belongs in the `FilterSymbol` method. It expects the same parameters as its prececessor `WalkTree` but without the delegate.

```
private static void FilterSymbol<TResult>(
    SemanticModel model,
    SyntaxNode node,
    HashSet<TResult> results)
{
    var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol as IFieldSymbol;
    if (symbol != null && results.Contains(symbol))
    {
        results.Remove(symbol);

        var assignmentNode = node.Parent as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
        if (assignmentNode?.Left == node)
        {
            results.Remove(symbol);
        }

        var argumentNode = node.Parent as ArgumentSyntax;
        if (argumentNode?.RefOrOutKeyword != null)
        {
            results.Remove(symbol);
        }

        var postFixExpressionNode = node.Parent as PostfixUnaryExpressionSyntax;
        if (postFixExpressionNode != null)
        {
            results.Remove(symbol);
        }

        var preFixExpressionNode = node.Parent as PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax;
        if (preFixExpressionNode != null)
        {
            results.Remove(symbol);
        }
    }
}
```

The use would be now without the return value as this is no longer necessary. Additionally, it may required to specify the result type:

```
WalkTree<IFieldSymbol>(context.SemanticModel, classNode, membersCanBeReadonly, FilterSymbol);
```

*(I hope I have the generics right)*